# How to batch run an FME workspace on a feature basis?

Tags: fme-form, features, network, batch

Not sure about the title of my question...

My point is to run an entire workspace for each feature contained in a reader.

In python this would look like:

```
for s in bus_stops:
    run_workspace(s)
```

Basically my workspace works as following :

- reads 1 bus stop
- reads a road network
- computes network cost for the input bus stop (NetworkCostCalculator)
- outputs contours

The workspace works if input is limited to 1 bus stop (une source only for NetworkCostCalculator).

By now I have split my input bus stops in as many feature types and I batch run my workspace on them but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to achieve that.

Comment: A tester and a workspace runner will run your features separate bus stops. http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/WorkspaceRunner

Answer (score 4):

you could do it in a pythonCaller transformer

see fmeobjects python API Reference: http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Objects_Python_API/fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner-class.html

```
import fmeobjects

    for s in bus_stops
      runner = fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner()
      #workspace is a path and parameters is a key value dict
      runner.runWithParameters(workspace, parameters)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a Group-By in the NetworkCostCalculator? i.e. you group-by on a bus stop ID and the transformer runs once per bus stop feature

Otherwise, as noted above, the WorkspaceRunner is your friend here.

Edit: In fact, now I think on it, the Group-By would be more efficient. It should only need the network once for all bus stops - whereas if you batch this (either in Python or a WorkspaceRunner) you're reading the network features once per bus stop.

Comment: It was my first idea, but for some reason it didn't work. With 2.000 stops and 300.000 network features, network reading time will be my major concern. I'll give it another try.